# Passing NSArray from Objective C to Javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I want to pass the `NSArray` from **Objective C** on a button's click to **JavaScript**. How do I pass it? I'm able to call the **JavaScript** method with parameters but how do I achieve this?

Comment: Pretty hard to give an answer if we don't know how you're using Obj-C and JS together. UIWebView with some custom code? Running your own JS engine?

Comment: ya i am loading the webview on button's click and calling the javascript using stringEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

Comment: my code on button's click is:

Answer (score 1):

Pass an array as a parameter from objective c to Javasctipt

```
NSString *arrayStr = [currentArray componentsJoinedByString:@"','"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"initActivity(['%@'])", arrayStr ]];
```

Comment: extension for the above answer:
Here you are able to send a string in arrayformat.
In Java Script you are able to retrieve String.
If you want to convert as an Array
Follow the steps:
              // converting json string to Array format
              var jsonEle =   JSON.parse(arrayOfJSONElements);

Answer (score 0):

If your array contains primitive values or strings you can do the following:

```
NSArray *objs; 
NSString *arrayStr = [objs componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSString *jsFunc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"jsFuncName([%@])", arrayStr];
[webViev stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsFunc];
```

If your array contains some other type, you need to stringify each object before calling `componentsJoinedByString`.

Comment: then how will i recieve the array in javascript??

Comment: bt here the value will be passes as variables....... i want to directly pass the array and access that array in javascript

Comment: @FX here the array will be passed as string for ex-jsFuncNAme(02,ertjkh,krtj) and i woll have to handle each element of array individually as a variable ...whereas i want to access it as an array in javascript

Comment: Assume: `NSArray *obj = @[@"one", @"two", @"three"]` then you can have a js function `jsFuncName(inputArray)`where inputArray will have 3 elements when invoked with `obj`.

Comment: can u plz elleborate on this.how will i pass it and how will i handle it.

Comment: Can you show me your javascript function and the obj-c code where you want to invoke you js function?

Comment: my code on button's click is: NSArray arrPass=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1212",@"HEllo",@"347khf",nil]; NSSTring *function=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"getSet(%@')",arrPass; [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:function]; now how o handle this array in javascript,can u plz tell me

Comment: You have an error in your code: `@"getSet(%@')"` should be `@"getSet([%@])"` You need the square brackets for the js function to interpret is an array.

Comment: i tried with this as well but javascript is not getting called.

Comment: it is loading the webView bt not calling the Javascript method

Comment: @user2284897: I could be wrong, but I don't think there's a way to pass Obj-C structures by reference, they're just too different. They're probably serialized/converted in some way, even if you pass a `NSArray` to the JS function like @Markus said.

Comment: thanks every1 , i was able to acheive it.... first of all we will have to convert the string in this form - getSet(['ssas','3432','dsf']) and then call the javascript...